# How to grant bind request from specific Android activity/service?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-service

I have service that should only serve (meaning allow binding) to specific group of Android activity/services. For example, what if I only want to grant bind request from my own applications ? Or application who's package declaration is 'com.foo' ? Is there a way in Android to achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to retain some sort of control over who is allowed to bind to your service, then you can look into creating your own permissions. Create your permission in such a way that any app that wants to use your service needs to have added the permission into their manifest.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html

Answer (score 1):

All components are not *exported* by default, so they can only be used from the same app/package. This behaviour is controlled by the `exported` attribute in the component tags of the *AndroidManifest.xml* file. For example see the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) for `Activity`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. If the service is exported (true) then other components can launch it. Thats fairly clear in docs, but what if a service is already running, and other component from different application requests to bind. Can a service reject it ?

Comment: You can define a permission in the `service` tag. Or you can return `null` from `onBind()`.